# How to create a stereo audio file from two mono audio file with code in android

Tags: java, android

I have 2 audio file

I want to put them in a stereo file with code. one in left channel and one in right channel

how should I write this stereo file? please give me a code or library

thank you dears :)

Comment: I'm waiting for a correct answer yet dears :)

Comment: why do u keep using the word dear? have you read the [faq]? understood it? keep questions to the point

Answer (score 2):

For code example, you can refer to one wave interface. Here is a good one for me:

> https://code.google.com/p/upp-mirror/source/browse/trunk/bazaar/plugin/wav/

You can read wave.h as your main API to read both mono audio file and write into stereo audio file.

Answer (score 1):

Two methods:

1. Use tool software such as "CoolEdit Pro". Open both audio files, and create a new one with format "stereo", then copy 1st audio file and paste into that new created file on "Left Channel", and copy 2nd one and paste on "Right Channel". Finally, save as any format as you want.
2. Write a small program to read both files and merge into one file, just follow these sequence: Read one sample from file 1, write this sample to target file; Read one sample from file 2, write this sample to target file.

Comment: thank you dear but I mean how to do this with code.